# Insert session variable into database with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a dynamic table that allows users to add/edit and delete records from a database with ajax. The table is actually originally from [here](http://www.infotuts.com/ajax-table-add-edit-delete-rows-dynamically-jquery-php/)

It works fine except now I want to be able to add a session variable (username) to the database along with the other records. For all my searching and reading I just can't figure out how to do it...unfortunately my jquery and javascript knowledge is very limited. I would greatly appreciate any help.

This is the 'add' part of script.js and I have been adding a username field to the table.

```
  var data='';
  var action = '';
  var savebutton = "<input type='button' class='ajaxsave' value='Save'>";
  var updatebutton = "<input type='button' class='ajaxupdate' value='Update'>";
  var cancel = "<input type='button' class='ajaxcancel' value='Cancel'>";
  var pre_tds; 
  var field_arr = new Array('text','text','text','text', 'text');
  var field_pre_text= new Array('Enter production','Enter channel','Enter role','Enter company', 'username');
  var field_name = new Array('production','channel','role','company', 'username'); 
 $(function(){
 $.ajax({
         url:"DbManipulate.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:"actionfunction=showData",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){

          $('#demoajax').html(response);
          createInput();

        }

       });


 $('#demoajax').on('click','.ajaxsave',function(){



           var production =  $("input[name='"+field_name[0]+"']");
       var channel = $("input[name='"+field_name[1]+"']");
       var role =$("input[name='"+field_name[2]+"']");
       var company = $("input[name='"+field_name[3]+"']");
           var username =  SOMETHING LIKE THIS.....$_SESSION['username'];

       if(validate(production,channel,role,company)){
       data = "production="+production.val()+"&channel="+channel.val()+"&role="+role.val()+"&company="+company.val()+"&username="+username.val()+"&actionfunction=saveData";
       $.ajax({
         url:"DbManipulate.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
           if(response!='error'){
              $('#demoajax').html(response);
          createInput();
             }
        }

       });
      } 
      else{
       return;
      }   
       });**strong text**
```

And this is the 'save and show' part of DbManipulate.php where I have a added username field to the table.

```
<?php
include('db.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['actionfunction']) && $_REQUEST['actionfunction']!=''){
$actionfunction = $_REQUEST['actionfunction'];

   call_user_func($actionfunction,$_REQUEST,$con);
}
function saveData($data,$con){

  $username = $con->real_escape_string($data['username']);
  $production = $con->real_escape_string($data['production']);
  $channel = $con->real_escape_string($data['channel']);
  $role = $con->real_escape_string($data['role']);
  $company = $con->real_escape_string($data['company']);
  $sql = "insert into credits (production,channel,role,company, username) values('$production','$channel','$role','$company', '$username')";
  if($con->query($sql)){
    showData($data,$con);
  }
  else{
  echo "error";
  }

}
function showData($data,$con){
  $sql = "select * from credits order by id asc";
  $data = $con->query($sql);
  $str='<tr class="head"><td>production</td><td>channel</td><td>role</td><td>company</td><td></td><td>username</td><td>id</td></tr>';
  if($data->num_rows>0){
   while( $row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      $str.="<tr id='".$row['id']."'><td>".$row['production']."</td><td>".$row['channel']."</td><td>".$row['role']."</td><td>".$row['company']."</td><td><input type='button' class='ajaxedit' value='Edit'/> <input type='button' class='ajaxdelete' value='Delete'></td><td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['id']."</td></tr>";
   }
   }else{
    $str .= "<td colspan='5'>No Data Available</td>";
   }
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite a lot of code for a question with no specifics.  IF you pare down your methodology to a bare minimum, I think you'll figure it out yourself.  Start working on a PHP fiddle to show what you're doing _without_ any unnecessary business logic and you'll probably figure it out before you're done.  IF not, post the fiddle and we'll try to help you.  ( Note the database doesn't need to be part of the proof of concept; that's not what you're struggling with I think ).

Answer (score 0):

I have'nt really read all of your details. But reading your question alone, I think you can simply create a session in the server with this pseudocode:

1. In JavaScript, send session name and session value to the server using
   Ajax (GET or POST)
2. In the PHP server, get session name and session value
3. Create the session using gathered values

The PHP script would be like:

```
<?php
   // if the script is called via POST method.
   if($_POST) {
      $_SESSION[$POST['session_name'] = $_POST['session_value']];
   }
   // if the script is called via GET method
   if($_GET) {
      $_SESSION[$GET['session_name'] = $_GET['session_value']];
   }
?>
```

With this script, the only thing you need to do now is to send it the data it needs to create the session. I think you have that already.

Comment: remember to put `session_start()` after <?php